# Pandas Merge between 2 CSV files results in a NaN returns and it should not be

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
website_text = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_New_Mexico_locations_by_per_capita_income').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_text,'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

***I am merging this file***

```
data = []
for row in table_rows:
    data.append([t.text.strip() for t in row.find_all('td')])

df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Rank', 'County', 'Per capita income', 'Median household income', 'Median family income', 'Population', 'Number of households'])
df = df[~df['Rank'].isnull()]  #Ignore Not Assigned rows

df.head(35)
```

With a "insert code" written personal CSV file.

Using this code:

```
df_NewMex = pd.merge(df2, df_latlong, how='left', left_on = 'County', right_on = 'County')
df_NewMex.drop("Rank", axis=1, inplace=True)
df_NewMex.head(33)
```

And I'm receiving a lot of 
[NaN output photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/633rF.png)

Please help. I have made sure the county names are identical, no lost spaces, etc. I am at a loss and have been troubleshooting this for the better part of 2 hours.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see this post on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [don't post photos of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3888719). Be specific with your question, and to the extent possible, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what do you want exactly you want to get rid of `NaN` or You want to find the lat and long for your `NaN` values please be specific

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am trying to add the latitude/longitude coordinates csv dataframe to (df_latlong) to an existing county dataframe (df2).

I need each field to have the value filled in but it doesn't appear to be

Comment: Do I need to use a different join type? I have played around with a few and get different outputs but none include the lat/long that I need

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I had an extra column in one file that needed to be removed. Once that was done it was fixed.

Sorry for my rambling

Answer (score 0):

I needed to drop 'rank' column in df2 before merging file with df_latlong, not after.

Rookie/newb mistake. I appreciate your help